# Java Class Constructor Parameters with range limits

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to Java and I'm asking this question just to help me better understand OOP.

Let's say I'm defining a new Class called Hour. To instantiate this Class, we need to specify an integer to indicate the hour of this instance.

```
Hour hr = new Hour(16); // this means to define an hour that indicates 4pm.
```

So when we define the Hour Class here, the parameter for the constructor should within the range [0, 24). How can we define such a parameter and can I throw an error when a parameter that is out of this range is specified?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you re-invent the wheel, and not use the pre-defined Date API? Or even better use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the *compiler* to catch the error, you could define an enum for the hours, then use that as the parameter of the constructor of `Hour`. This might make the `Hour` class useless, though.

```
public class Hours {
    _1, _2, _3, // etc.
}

public class Hour {
    public Hour(Hours hour) { // no need for runtime check here, can not be wrong}
}

Hour hour = new Hour(Hours._3);
```

This technique may not be the best here, but generally it is better to rely on compile time checks than on runtime ones.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.
>   example

```
public class Hour
{
    Hour(int hour)
    {
       if(hour>=24 || hour<0)
        {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour should in the range of [0-23].");
       }
   }
  ...............
}
```

Comment: Make it `hour >= 24`. And it would be better to throw `InstantiationException`, with appropriate message, as that's inside a constructor.

Comment: @RohitJain yes we can throw `InstantiationException` also,but it is a checked exception we need to `throws` it.

Comment: @RohitJain hm... No problem in that.But I think am thinking unnecessary here.Thank you for your suggestion I will update the answer.

Comment: No leave it as it is. I think this is ok.

Comment: @RohitJain `InstantiationException` is wrong  here, it should clearly be `IllegalArgumentException`, becaus this is what it is. The `InstantiationException` is used inthe context of reflection. Read the docs, please.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Java unlike Pascal and other languages does not support range types. You can however use the other techniques.

The simplest way is to check the value in code.

```
class Hour {
    private final int h;
    public Hour(int h) {
        if (h < 0 || h >= 24) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are only 24 hours");
        }
        this.h = h;
    }
}
```

You can also use more sophisticated techniques. Take a look on java [Validation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html)
In this case your code will look like:

```
class Hour {
    @Max(23)
    @Min(0)
    private final int h;
    public Hour(int h) {
        this.h = h;
    }
}
```

But you will have to use one of available implementations of this API and invoke it.